# discover if ip address is DHCP or static

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, ip, static-ip-address

im trying to get in c programing (LINUX) what kind of ip I have DHCP or static.
Does someone know how do that??
I extract my ip using struct ifaddrs; it will be nice to find out if that stucture can provide the information. 
thanks on advance :)

Comment: What platform, OS, etc ?

Comment: What do you hope to do with the information? Bear in mind that there can be non-static IP addresses not assigned with DHCP (eg those assigned with RARP or BOOTP); and static addresses assigned through DHCP.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RARP & BOOTP but I think it's not relevent. I need to extract the data that have been choosen from the setup menu in network configuration while there is only two choices there DHCP or STATIC for eth0. 
I need this information only for display.. I've build and lcd module to a device that display data like LAN ip address.

Comment: @azulay7: Then what you need is to read the configuration file that the network configuration utility produces.  That will vary depending on the utility in use - different Linux distributions use different network configuration files.

Comment: yes this is ehat I ment... I fount it under /etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0
case closed! :)

Answer (score 5):

That property is not something you can deduce statically from the IP address alone.

You can probably make a *guess* by determining if the IP address is in the "non-routable" series (10.x.y.z or 192.168.x.y), but the address could just as well have been manually assigned.

Figuring out if the system has a current lease from a DHCP server is (very) platform-dependent, and will require information that is not in the IP address itself.

Comment: I didn't mean to deduce it from the ip. I want to discover it with another function if there is any..